# case without statement and break

Tags: c, switch-statement, rpn

I'm dealing with RPN calculator and I've found some approach that's using the `switch` where some of the `case` doesn't have any expression and `break` statement:

Here is my approach that's using this algorithm unfortunately it's not working properly
As an input for the function I'm using the array of `struct` defines as follow:

```
num OPERATORS {val, PLUS, MINUS, MULTI, DIV, SIN, COS, O_PAREN, C_PAREN, END};
typedef struct value {

    double number;
    enum OPERATORS oper;
};
```

And here is the RPN parser:

```
void get_the_rpn(struct value values[], struct value rpn_values[], int length) {

    struct value stack[256]; //stack for keeping the values
    int i; //iterator
    int pos; //postion on stack

    i=pos=0;
    //go trough each element in values and reprase it to the rpn format
    while(values[i].oper != END) {

        //check first if current element isn't number
        if(values[i].oper == val) {
            rpn_values[i] = values[i];
            pos++;
        }
        //current element isn't number is an operator
        else
            switch(values[i].oper)
            {
                case PLUS:
                    ;
                case DIV:
                    while (pos && stack[pos-1].oper != O_PAREN &&
                                  stack[pos-1].oper != PLUS &&
                                  stack[pos-1].oper != MINUS) {
                        rpn_values[i] = stack[--pos];
                    }
                    stack[pos++] = values[i];
                    break;
                case MINUS:
                    while (pos && stack[pos-1].oper != O_PAREN) {
                        rpn_values[i] = stack[--pos];
                    }
                    stack[pos++] = values[i];
                    break;
                case MULTI:
                    ;
                case O_PAREN:
                    stack[pos++] = values[i];
                    break;
                case C_PAREN:
                    while (stack[pos-1].oper != O_PAREN) {
                        rpn_values[i] = stack[--pos];
                    }
                    pos--;
                    break;
                case SIN:
                    rpn_values[i] = values[i];
                    break;  //edited
                case COS:
                    rpn_values[i] = values[i];
                    break;  //edited
            }
        i++;

    }
}
```

The question mostly is why for `PLUS` and `MULTI` in the `case` clause there is no statement simply `;`?

If someone would like to see whole code and maybe could found the bug here is the whole `calculate.c` program http://pastebin.com/WteqbmJg

Comment: A equally entertaining question would be why is the same *not* done for `SIN` above `COS`. Its called *falling through* a switch-case, btw, and the fiend that wrote this should be consistent. They should also provide a proper `default:` for catching unexpected values like `val` or `END` (though those can't technically make it into the switch with the preamble code in-place).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `switch()` statement, control is passed to the matching `case`.

A `case` without a `break` (or anything else that might redirect control) will continue to execute the code in the next 'case' (including the `default` case).

In the question code, the reason that `PLUS` has no statement (even the `;` is optional), is that it 'falls-through' to the `DIV` case.  Just as the `MULTI` case falls-through to the `O_PAREN` case,

All very legitimate C coding.

Comment: True its legitimate coding.  Suggest a coding style that has a comment indicating intentional fall through.  `case PLUS: /* fall through */  ;`

Comment: @chux, agreed.  In the question code, such a construct is easily overlooked.

Comment: @chux likewise agreed. If you don't terminate a case label with a break, you better put a comment specifying that intent so the "helpful" engineer that follows you knows it was intentional.

Comment: That's what I thought but in this approach what is happening with the `'+'` operator? It's not going into the `stack`...
My solution is some combination of preprepared algorithm for RPN the use of `struct` array was my idea, not pretty sure if t;s correct.
p.s. I added the `break` after `COS` and `SIN`